# py2exe and assimulo - No module named algebraic

Tags: python, py2exe, assimulo

I am trying to build an executable using py2exe on a soft that uses the library assimulo (differential equation solver). The problem encountered is that during execution I receive:

> ImportError: No module named algebraic

The exact error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 89, in <module>
    from simulation.simulation import Simulation
  File "simulation\simulation.pyc", line 18, in <module>
    manages all the action linked to a simulation, like running, saving, replay, etc...
  File "solver\assimuloSolver.pyc", line 7, in <module>
    Explicit solver to choose in the list of assimulo solvers:
  File "assimulo\solvers\__init__.pyc", line 25, in <module>
  File "assimulo\solvers\kinsol.pyc", line 12, in <module>
  File "assimulo\solvers\kinsol.pyc", line 10, in __load
  File "kinsol.pyx", line 1, in init assimulo.solvers.kinsol (assimulo\solvers\kinsol.c:19711)
ImportError: No module named algebraic
```

Here qe can see that it is line 7 that produces my troubles, and this line is

```
from assimulo.solvers import Radau5DAE
```

the setup.py file for py2exe looks like the following:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from py2exe.build_exe import py2exe
import sys
from glob import glob
import matplotlib

data_files = [("Microsoft.VC90.CRT", glob(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\*.*'))]
data_files.extend(matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles())
sys.path.append("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\VC\\redist\\x86\\Microsoft.VC90.CRT")

excludes = ['_gtkagg', '_tkagg']
includes = [
            "scipy.sparse.csgraph._validation", 
            "scipy.special._ufuncs_cxx", 
            ]

opts = {
    "py2exe": {
        "includes":includes,
        "excludes":excludes,
    }
}

setup(name = "MySoft", 
      version = "0.1", 
      data_files=data_files, 
      windows=[{"script":"main.py"}], options=opts)
```

If someone has a clue, I would be very interested.
Thanks

Comment: Where is algebraic coming from?  If it is in the assimulo package you should be able to force py2exe to include by using the 'packages' option.

Comment: Yes, it is due to assimulo, and the package is located in : C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\assimulo. then using the option: py2exe:{"packages":['algebraic']}, but I don't no how to specify the package? does I need to give the entire path? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was obtained by adding, in the includes option, the algebraic package this way:

```
includes = ["assimulo.algebraic"]
```

One must also be sure that the library is added to the PATH variable. If not, one can simply add sys.path.append("path to the library"), which in my case was

```
sys.path.append("C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\assimulo")
```

in the setup file

Thanks for the help
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I have found py2exe failing to include packages, even when listed in the packages option, but have found that if I import the package in setup.py it starts to work so try adding, near the top of `setup.py`:

```
import assimulo
```

You will sometimes find that even

```
if False:
    import assimulo
```

will work, (use this is `assimulo` does a lot of setting up on import).

Comment: Hi, I just tried your solution, but py2exe cannot find the package: No module named algebraic. I tried to import assimulo, even assimulo.algebraic while adding 'algebraic' to the packages list. Thanks for your help

Comment: I realized that algebraic is actually a .pyd file, would that be a reason why it cannot find it?

Comment: It may be one of the _reasons_ that py2exe does not find it - and it looks like it needs to be present where your exe can find it, in the same directory as your executable should do.

Comment: It didn't help either to add the file in the dist folder. When I try to add the package in the packages list, it cannot find the package while py2exe executes the "searching for required modules" step. Thanks